# Custom header description in UITableView

Tags: iphone

Is Apple using a documented method of the SDK in Settings.app, or is it some kind of custom cell / custom header description of a grouped TableView ?

"Storage" is `titleForHeaderInSection:`. What is "8.6 GB Available - 5.1 GB Used" ?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Storage** is the header for `section 0`, **8.6 GB Available    5.1 GB Used** is the footer text for `section 0`. Asphalt starts `section 1`. Does this make sense to you?

`Section 0` would contain 0 cells.

[image]

### Example Code

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView{
    return 2;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section{

    if ( section ==0 ) return 0;
    if ( section ==1 ) return 20;

    return 0;
}

- (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {

    if ( section ==0 ) return @"Storage";
    if ( section ==1 ) return nil;

    return nil;
}

- (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)section {

    if ( section ==0 ) return @"9.11 TB Available              4.29 GB Used";
    if ( section ==1 ) return nil;

    return nil;
}
```

Comment: Yes, much quicker solution. However, putting a `UIView` above the tableView is more customizable I suppose.

Comment: However, in this code you will have to get clever with the spacing. Adjusting the about of text on each side will cause the text to kick down to the next row, which won't look good.

Answer (score 0):

They have probably put in a custom view in the header. So, it looks like they are using section titles but in fact they have a custom view that is formatted like it.

See this: [Put a UIView into a UITableView Header](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4968738/put-a-uiview-into-a-uitableview-header)

For some documentation on the matter, see http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITableViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html

You can find the delegate methods you need to implement under `Modifying the Header and Footer of Sections`.

Answer (score 0):

A custom UIView with clear background color, and insert it into tableView's headerView.